# Setting max-height in scss prevents code from executing

Tags: reactjs, sass, web-component, storybook, tsx

I am using React.js in combination with Storybook to create a component library.

While making the search bar component I wanted to add an autocomplete dropdown. The dropdown works just as expected however due to using the `max-height` to control the drop down and give it a nice animation it won't execute the function that it should in my tsx file.

I have tried setting it programatically however this would mean for me that I would have to add new props to my `Input`component which I don't really want to do so I was wondering if there is another way to do it?

In my Searchbar.tsx I have this code which is responsible for mapping the options. Here I add the onClick which doesn't get triggered:

```
const renderAutoCompleteOptions = () => {
    return (
      <div className={`${styles.autoCompleteOptions}`}>
        {filteredOptions.map((option: string, index: number) => (
          <div
            key={index}
            onClick={() => {
              setInputValue(option);
              onAutoCompleteSelect?.(option);
            }}
          >
            {option}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  };
```

And here is the relevant scss which is causing the problem:

```
.searchbarContainer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  gap: 5px;

  &:focus-within .autoCompleteOptions {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    max-height: 200px;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease, opacity 0.1s ease, visibility 0s 0s;
  }

  .autoCompleteOptions {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    max-height: 0;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease, opacity 0.3s ease, visibility 0s 0.4s;
    position: absolute;
    top: 90%;
    left: 5px;
    right: 0;
    background-color: white;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px;
    z-index: 2;
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
}
```

I noticed that when I set the `animation transition duration` of the `max-height` to multiple seconds then it works however the animation becomes super slow as you can imagine.

Comment: `max-height` is a CSS property and it's irrelevant that you're using SCSS as a preprocessor. You should update your title and tags to reflect that as you might get a better answer. (storybook and tsx should also be removed)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I tried removing only the `max-height: 0;` and then it works. It seems that it really is the css which is the problem.